# identify presence of an Input tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have this scenario....
in a webpage, i will have few input/ textboxes... sometimes 2 or sometimes 3. this will be displayed/ created based on my need.. but once the page is displayed on clicking of a button, i wish to know how many input tags are available.. with the id i might populate with...

is it possible for me to identify if a Input box is available or not with id. i do not wish to abruptly stop the pgm, if it isn't present.

i use html, css3 and javascript in my code (php being server coding).

hope am clear. let me know if not.
thanks in advance!

Comment: An ID must be unique. Are you changing the ID of each so that they're not identical?

Comment: You should add the requested clarification to your question if you're going to accept an answer. We barely know the question so we don't know the solution you've chosen since multiple were provided to make up for lack of detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i wish to know how many input tags are available

You can use `getElementsByTagName` to know if there are `<input>` tags. `getElementsByTagName` returns an array-like structure (NodeList?) and has a `length` property to know how many were retrieved.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
if(inputs.length){
  // there's inputs on the page
} else {
  // n
}
```

---

> i wish to know how many input tags are available.. with the id

If you want to get the input *with the given ID*, use `getElementById`. Note that IDs are supposed to be unique (will always be one and only one) and no two elements should have the same ID.

```
var inputWithGivenId = document.getElementById('the-id');
if(inputWithGivenId){
  // `inputWithGivenId` refers to the element with `id="the-id"`
} else {
  // no element of given id
}
```

---

> is it possible for me to identify if a Input box is available or not with id.

Well, IDs are supposed to be unique. But if you're considering a set of `<input>` you want targetted, but not all `<input>`, consider using `class` instead.

To fetch elements with given class name from the DOM, use `getElementsByClassName`. `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like structure (NodeList?) and has a `length` property to know how many were retrieved.

```
var elementsWithClassName = document.getElementsByClassName('the-class');
if(elementsWithClassName.length){
  // there's elements on the page with the given class
  // You may want to check if they're <input>. Any element could use the class
} else {
  // there's elements on the page with the given class
}
```

Comment: *"...with the id i might populate with..."*

Comment: @cookiemonster But the OP sounded like *"I may have written my HTML with inputs with the same id"*. While `getElementById` would be the right choice for IDs, I'm offering an alternative.

Comment: Right, it seems he wants a specific set and that they may have the same ID (which is wrong). So neither `gEBTN` nor `gEBI` would be quite right.

Comment: @cookiemonster Language barrier most probably (referring to tymeJV's thread). But basing from the title, *"identify presence of an Input tag"* - that's about as clear as we could get off of it.

Comment: thanks all... the length concept seems working.. thanks a lot! :)

Comment: hi @JosephtheDreamer , facing strange issue.. the value is getting passed to the variable... when used
var abc=getelementbyId('demo')

but when i do abc.length - i get it as undefined:(

Comment: @SamuelMathews `getElementById` - watch the case.